# Remove characters after "\" in a Dataframe

Tags: python, string, dataframe, data-cleaning

How can I remove all the characters in the column "Player" after the names? For example: Max Aarons\774cf58b. I only want to have the first part: Max Aarons and delete the rest "\774cf58b"

[image: Table]

Comment: Most languages support an operation like first index of and a String spilt operation.

Comment: Programming language is Python

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`pandas.DataFrame.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
def remove_after_slash(string):
    if '/' not in string: return string
    return string.split('/')[0]

df['names'].apply(remove_after_slash)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot -- that worked. I just had to add a second backslash.

```
def remove_after_slash(string):
    if '\\' not in string: return string
    return string.split('\\')[0]

df['Player'] = df['Player'].apply(remove_after_slash)
```